# Deleted blobs still showing in Azure Portal

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I've run a process to delete approximately 1500 blobs from my Azure storage service. The code I've used to do this (in a loop) is essentially this:

```
var blob = BlobStorageContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(blobName);

if (await blob.ExistsAsync(cancellationToken))
{
    await blob.DeleteAsync(cancellationToken);
}
```

I went through both the Azure Portal and Azure Storage Explorer, and it looks like all the blobs that should have been deleted are still there. However, when I try to actually access the file via the URL, I get a ResourceNotFound error. So it seems the data has been deleted, but the storage service seems to think that the blob should still be there. Am I doing something wrong, or does the storage service need time to catch up, in a sense, to all the delete operations I performed?

Answer (score 0):

You can try doing a list blob operation for the container and that will give you an up to date view of what blobs are still present in your account. Accessing the blob from the internet URI will come back as ResourceNotFound if the blob isn't public even if it is still present in the container. Is it possible your calls are failing but your code is eating the exceptions?